# Change wpf style from viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a DataTemplate:

```
 <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type local:ConnectionViewModel}"
            >
            <!-- The connection is represented by a curved arrow. -->
            <ca:CurvedArrow

                    StrokeThickness="2"
                    Points="{Binding Points}"
                    Fill="{StaticResource connectionBrush}"
                    Stroke="{StaticResource connectionBrush}"
                />

        </DataTemplate>
```

This represent all the connector i have in my view.
What I want to do is to set a different fill and stroke for specific **specific** connectors from the viewmodel. 
How can I achive that?

Comment: Did you try to implement a template selector class?

Comment: My wpf skills are really low. Can you reference me to an example?
Or maybe give her here as an answer?
To your question, no I didn't

Comment: @Yogevnn - If you have properties in your Viewmodel (ideally UI stuff should not be put there), bind the properties with `Fill` and `Stroke`.

Comment: @Yogevnn, create a data template for each kind of connector and then select the appropriate template in a template selector class, which sits OUTSIDE your view model.  If the selection is formulaic, the View Model shouldn't care or even be involved.

Comment: I think that would do the job because this view is not mvvm and doesn't have to be. I'll check that and update if it worked, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be avoiding any UI objects in viewmodel.

For the mentioned use case, you can make use of Converters and continue to only have business object level information in your viewmodel.

For instance, you Connection class can hold a property of `enum : ConnectorType {Arrow,Circle,Rectangle}` and then you can write a [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) which converts enum type to desired color brush. Sample code below:

```
//Inside Resources. local=namespace where you have this converter
   <local:ConnectorType2BrushConverter x:Key="ConnectorType2BrushConverter" />
....
    <ca:CurvedArrow

                        StrokeThickness="2"
                        Points="{Binding Points}"
                        Fill="{Binding Path=ConnectorType, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ConnectorType2BrushConverter}"
                    />

    ....

        public class ConnectorType2BrushConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var connectorType = (ConnectorType)value;
                if (connectorType == ConnectorType.Arrow)
                {
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(1, 1, 1));
                }
                else    .....
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for that! 
I have one question, in this case how can i set each connector ConnectorType? Because the binding is for the enum. Should i also have a property?

Comment: And also, how do i declare the convertor in the xaml?

Comment: Yes. You will need to have property in your Connection class. Updated code with declaration for Converter.

Comment: I'm getting an error inside the converter class:

Error 1 The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type (ViewModels.ConnectionViewModel.ConnectorType' is a non-nullable value type)

Comment: Code modified. Aplogies, didn't post a compiled/executed code. It's because enum is a struct - you can hard cast value to enum directly.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! You had nothing to apologize for, you helped more i could imagine